# c# charts query in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, variables, charts

I have created a program which extracts metadata out of a PST.  This data has then been stored in a text file.

I am trying to create a set of charts/graphs which will represent the data which I have pulled out.  Is it possible using Visual Studio 2010 to create a bar chart for example using variables or by reading specific data which I have written to the text file.

I know that VS 2010 does have the inbuilt chart feature; however, I can't seem to get it to work off values held in a variable (only from databases, a service, an object or SharePoint).

I am new to programming in C# and using Visual Studio so I may be missing something very simple!  I have googled for days and have had no light.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Katie.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about ZedGraph, it's both very simple and powerful open-source chart library written completely in c#. I personally used it several times and it was really easy and fast to work with.

It has any type of chart you can think of, including pie charts, Chinese candles (for stocks), simple bar charts.. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/

Answer (score 0):

Using the Microsoft Chart Control for .Net 3.5, and the Chart Control add-in for Visual Studio 2008, you should be able created charts for Windows and Web application. Although it does not work with unstructured data, like the text file, it can work with Object data. If you can read the data in the text file and populate objects with it, you can bind it to a column chart easily.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1344-using-chart-control-in-visual-studio-2010-web-and-windows-explained.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I'll take a look at the link now.